# find all variables in a mathematical expression

Tags: python, regex

I have a mathematical expression, for example : "x45 + x3/2 + ln(x1 - x45)" and I want to create a function, called

```
find_variables(expression)
```

which should return the list of the variables contained in the expression, with only one occurrence if the variable appears twice or more in the expression. Here, L = ["x45", "x3", "x1"]

I thought I might use regexes of this kind :

```
pattern = re.compile(x\d+)
```

but I don't know how to match then stock the results. Can anyone help me ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: `set([x.replace('/', '') for x in re.findall(r'x\d+(?:/\d+)?', expression)])`?

Comment: `L = ["x45", "x32", "x1"]`? Should that second one be `x3`, since it's the variable being divided by two.

Comment: [Have you looked at the documentation for the `re` package?](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall)

Comment: Ok thank you, just I don't understand all the elements, mostly why should do "x.replace("/", "")

Comment: oh yes you're right paxdiablo :) I'll just correct that

Comment: SO I understand Stribizew's answer now xD

Comment: But if you need `x3` and not `x32`, all you need is `re.findall` + `set`

Comment: You can use `\bx\d+\b` and return a set

Comment: Ok, now I understand, and is this guaranteeing to me that there will be no duplication ? That's the way .findall goes ?

Comment: The deduplication comes from the `set`, findall finds *all* occurrences, with duplicates.

Comment: ok GPhilo, that makes sense because in mathematics {1,2,5,6,9,9} = {1,2,5,6,9} for the sets thank you